# How to add a suffix to a property name in TextBox but save into another property?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this code:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelectedSystem.RightHandRootName, StringFormat=\{0\}_R}" MaxLength="31"/>
```

What I want is to bind the textbox text to SelectedSystem.RightHandRootName, but I want it to be pre-generated to "SelectedSystem.Name + _R" as in the code above.

The SelectedSystem.Name is a property bound before this textbox.

Comment: don't think I understand your problem  ? what is pregenerated and why you wanna suffix ?

Comment: @Muds I want that textbox value to be saved into my property, I want to pre-populate the property with other property value + my suffix.<TextBox Text={Binding property1}/> <TextBox Text={property1 + suffix}/> but I want the second textbox to save/bind the text to a property 2

Comment: so cant you do that in property getter ? if local value is not set return something else ?

Comment: @Muds I was looking for xaml-only solution. Thank you anyway.